# Does Isaiah 46:5 say that God has no equal?

Tags: isaiah

> Isaiah 46:5 ASV To whom will ye liken me, and make me equal, and
> compare me, that we may be like?

Having consideration of the rest of the bible, does this passage imply;

1. God has no equal
2. God has an equal – possibly Jesus
3. Is there more than one God – if so, which one is the true God

Please provide evidence from the bible to explain how you have come to your conclusion.

Comment: This is not a genuine question about the meaning of Isaiah 46:5 in its own context, and is either a 'stump the chumps' style question centred on a theological topic, or else a systematic theology question, both of which are off-topic. The question, answers, and OP's response to answers all consistently evidence this.

Comment: @SteveTaylor. Why not display what you call "evidence" to see whose comments  are not constructive. Why not read answers to see whose answers are constructive?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - no, I am not restoring dozens of comments with you bickering with others over theology just to defend closure of an off-topic question. If it does get reopened due to lack of evidence, that would probably be a good thing for both of us - any Question should be able to stand on its own merits, after all. If you wish to use comments to engage constructively with the answers to this question in the meantime, feel free.

Comment: @SteveTaylor. I just want your comment *"This is not a genuine question about the meaning of Isaiah 46:5 in its own context, and is either a 'stump the chumps' style question centred on a theological topic, or else a systematic theology question, both of which are off-topic. The question, answers, and OP's response to answers all consistently evidence this"* to be tried and tested, especially if it is used as a reason to close a Q.

Comment: @SteveTaylor The Q should be re-opened at best it may need a tweak - but it seems to be a valid Q, even if you disagree with the comments, the Q shouldn't be closed IMO.

Comment: @anothertheory - yes, anybody *could easily have* asked a valid and similar question on this verse, if it was asked genuinely and impartially. But in this case it's just here to grind an axe on a specific theological topic. The OP is pushing and asking for one very specific answer, and already seems to have their mind made up before ever asking the question. The question itself is loaded with lots of very specific phrases which make that intent clear.

Comment: @SteveTaylor. If your allegation is true, why don't you point out specifically what in the q that indicated to you that it was "just there to grind an axe on a specific theological topic.?

Comment: Actually, pretty much every word of text you've got there except for the Bible verse quote indicates that to me. The wonderfully nonsensical statement "are there other persons who are the only true God and God is not aware of this..." is perhaps the best example. It's literally a question that makes no sense, and is followed by a veiled accusation that anything other than your favoured view accuses God of lying. It's actually a fairly perfect example of a 'stump the chumps' style question. Feel free to search Meta for more thoughts on those.

Comment: @SteveTaylor. I find your decision to be arbitrary. If God says he has no equal, and Jesus says that his God is greater than him, but  somebody says that there is somebody that is equal to God, those statements needs to be examined.  But you already decided my Q to be nonsense. People who rather believe Jesus accusers on this subject can answer the question,. People who believe God and Jesus' God's statements can do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Isaiah makes a number of these sort of statements.  Let us begin with the very verse quoted by the OP.

**There is only ONE true God**

- Isa 46:5 - To whom will you liken Me or count Me equal? To whom will you compare Me, that we should be alike?
- Isa 44:6 - Thus says the LORD, the King and Redeemer of Israel, the LORD of Hosts: “I am the first and I am the last, and **there is no God but Me**.
- Isa 45:5, 6 - I am the LORD, and there is no other; there is **no God but Me**. I will equip you for battle, though you have not known Me, so that all may know, from where the sun rises to where it sets, that there is none but Me; I am the LORD, and there **is no other**.
- Deut 32:39 - See now that I am He; there is **no God besides Me**. I bring death and I give life; I wound and I heal, and there is no one who can deliver from My hand.
- Deut 4:35 - You were shown these things so that you would know that **the LORD is God; there is no other besides Him**.

Let there be no doubt that there is only One incomparable, God, our LORD Jehovah Almighty (and there is no other!) ... and in the NT we also have this:

- Matt 1:23 - “Behold, the virgin will be with child and will give birth to a son, and they will call Him Immanuel” (which means, “**The God with us**”).
- John 1:1, 14 - In the beginning was the Word and the Word was with God and **the Word was God** ... and the Word became flesh (compare Rev 19:13).
- John 1:18 - No one has ever seen God; the one and only God, the One in the bosom of the Father, He has made [Him] known.
- John 20:28 - Thomas replied, “The Lord of me and **the God of me**!”
- Acts 20:28 - Keep watch over yourselves and the entire flock of which the Holy Spirit has made you overseers. Be shepherds of the church of **God, which He purchased with His own blood**.
- Heb 1:8, 9 - But about the Son He says: “**Your throne, O God**, endures forever and ever, and justice is the scepter of Your kingdom. You have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; **therefore O God**, Your God has anointed You above Your companions with the oil of joy.”
- Titus 2:13 - while we wait for the blessed hope—the appearing of the glory of **our great God and Savior, Jesus Christ**
- 2 Peter 1:1 - This faith was given to you because of the justice and fairness of **Jesus Christ, our God and Savior**.

**Only one Savior**

- Isa 43:3, 11 - For I am the LORD your God, the Holy One of Israel, **your Savior**; ... I, yes I, am the LORD, and there is **no Savior but Me**.
- Isa 45:21 - Speak up and present your case— yes, let them take counsel together. Who foretold this long ago? Who announced it from ancient times? Was it not I, the LORD? There is no other God but Me, **a righteous God and Savior; there is none but Me**.

... and in the NT we read:

- Acts 4:12 - Salvation exists in no one else [ie, Jesus], for there is **no other name** under heaven given to men by which we must be saved.”
- 2 tim 1:10 - And now He has revealed this grace through the appearing of **our Savior, Christ Jesus**, who has abolished death and illuminated the way to life and immortality through the gospel
- Titus 1:4 - To Titus, my true child in our common faith: Grace and peace from God the Father and **Christ Jesus our Savior**.
- Titus 2:13 - while we wait for the blessed hope—the appearing of the glory of our great **God and Savior, Jesus Christ**,
- Titus 3:6 - This is the Spirit He poured out on us abundantly through **Jesus Christ our Savior**
- 2 Peter 1:1, 11 - To those who through the righteousness of our **God and Savior, Jesus Christ** have received a faith as precious as ours ... and you will receive a lavish reception into the eternal kingdom of our Lord and **Savior Jesus Christ**.

**The Only First and Last**

- Isa 41:4 - Who has performed this and carried it out, calling forth the generations from the beginning? I, the **LORD—the first and the last**—I am He.”
- Isa 44:6 - Thus says the LORD, the King and Redeemer of Israel, the LORD of Hosts: “**I am the first and I am the last, and there is no God but Me**.
- Isa 48:12 - Listen to Me, O Jacob, and Israel, whom I have called: I [the LORD] am He; **I am the first, and I am the last**.

... and in the NT we read:

- Rev 1:17, 18 - When I saw Him, I fell at His feet like a dead man. But He placed His right hand on me and said, “Do not be afraid. **I [Jesus] am the First and the Last**, the Living One. I was dead, and behold, now I am alive forever and ever! And I hold the keys of Death and of Hades.
- Rev 22:12, 13, 16 - “Behold, I am coming soon, and My reward is with Me, to give to each one according to what he has done. I am the Alpha and the Omega, **the First and the Last**, the Beginning and the End.” ... “I, Jesus, have sent My angel to give you this testimony for the churches. I am the Root and the Offspring of David, the bright Morning Star.”

... and so we could continue with other unique titles of YHWH in the OT and show how they are attached to Jesus in the NT such as, "I AM", "the Light", "Lord of Lords", "Lord of All", "Creator", "Shepherd", etc.

Further many passages in the OT are also applied to Jesus by quoting them in the NT such as:

- Deut 32:43 (LXX) is quoted by Heb 1:6
- Ps 45:6, 7 is quoted by Heb 1:8, 9
- Ps 102:25 - 27 is quoted by Heb 1:10 - 12.
- Isa 45:23 is quoted by Phil 2:10, 11, Rom 14:11
- Isa 40:3 is quoted by Matt 3:3 (cf v11)

... and so forth.  Thus, in answer to the OP's question, there are many passages that compare Jehovah, the LORD and say that the LORD of the OT is Jesus of the NT - same person.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any other true god than the one true god or God, then this view go against monotheism, i.e. only one God. The Bible is consistent about the teaching of monotheism (mono means only one). The Unitarians object to the fact of Christ sharing God's glory & equality Matt 25:31-46, Heb 1:3 John 17, Matt 28:28, then this authority and equality should not be inherently divine, or that this transfer of glory is contingent and real designation to a created man or angel that is Jesus. However, the scripture is clear about strict oneness and exclusive nature of God, he cannot possibly share and transfer his glory to anyone else in earth or heaven.

> Isa 40:25 To whom then will you compare me,
> that I should be like him? says the Holy One.
> Isa 42:8 I am the  Lord; that is my name;
> my glory I give to no other,
> nor my praise to carved idols.
> Isa 43:10-11 “You are my witnesses,” declares the  Lord,
> “and my servant whom I have chosen,
> that you may know and believe me
> and understand that I am he.
> Before me no god was formed,
> nor shall there be any after me.

Therefore, denying the oneness of Christ with his Father in their co-equal divine nature will imply polytheism. The Jews at the time of first century and before who interpreted the prophecies about the divine Messiah, never faced any conflict with their view of monotheism. The one [God is complex](https://www.biblestudying.net/history-of-judaism1.html) in nature and doesn't only act as the heavenly father, but also the Holy Spirit and the divine Memra who is the agent of the father and also becomes the Messiah/Son. There is no hierarchy of the persons or manifestations in the Trinity concerning the ontological nature. There are only subordinate roles in terms of the economy of trinity, (economic trinity); the Son is naturally subordinate to the Father in relation.

One of the reasons for objecting to the equality of the Son may be caused by overemphasis on the distinction among the three persons. You are not obligated to follow any traditional model of the Trinity doctrine, as the scholars recognize that the traditional Roman Trinity is itself in [error of subordinationism](https://www.reasonablefaith.org/writings/question-answer/jesus-the-only-begotten-of-the-father), by confusing the economy with ontology. In their eternally-begotten or the eternal generation nature of the Son. There cannot be any ontological change in the nature of God, hence there was no ontological begetting and emanation of persons from within the nature of God.

The Jewish [sources](https://www.biblestudying.net/rabbinic1.html) prove that the [trinity is not polytheism](https://www.biblestudying.net/trinity1.html). There is no reason to overcomplicate and confuse the coequality of the Son and the Father. They are not different beings but one. The Unitarians are ironically falling into the category of polytheism by viewing the Son as a separate god.

Answer (score 0):

> Isaiah 46:5 ASV To whom will ye liken me, and make me equal, and compare me, that we may be like?

Without need for special interpretation or special treatment of God's inspired word, we don't need to look far for the answers. Another answer provides a stellar list of verses to uphold the traditional view of the 3in1 God construct, however they are used in such a way to emphasise one reading/interpretation and are out of alignment with all other scripture.

There seems no dispute among rational bible readers that there is ONE God.

Who IS that one God? The bible calls Him Yahweh - he has a name and also many titles. Is Jesus called Yahweh anywhere? No. So the ONE God called Yahweh has no equal because that is what He tells us over and over.

Jesus also affirmed this - never claiming to be God himself, but pointing to *his* God and Father. If there is only one God - Jesus has pointed Him out and it isn't Jesus. The Apostles also affirm Jesus' grasp of this important truth.

> Now this is eternal life: that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you have sent. John 17:3

> “Let not your heart be troubled; you believe in God, believe ALSO in me.” John 14:1

> God has made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both Lord and Christ!” Acts 2:36

- To whom will ye liken me,

Jesus did not exist when Isaiah was written - the Gospels affirm this quite specifically. And no mention of a *holy son* before Jesus, corroborates this reality, except of course in many prophecies of the 'one to come'  - a man, not another God or about God becoming a man.

- make me equal,

Is Jesus equal with God? He never says he is - though they clearly share some *aspects* of equality - being holy, without sin, having the same authority (which God gave him) to name a few. But we are reminded that Jesus sits *next to God* so he can hardly *be* God and certainly not 'equal'. There is only ONE God, and Jesus is not Him.

- that we may be like?

Yes, again, Jesus is *very much like* God - bearing God's "image" and "form" and being His representative. Being the Immanuel does not make him God any more than the boy mentioned in Isaiah with the same title. But God is certainly *with us* in this Jesus, as His son, representative and servant.

Isaiah 46 does say God has no equal. With the NT revelations, nothing has changed. Jesus still has the same God he had when 'in the flesh' Rev 3, and is still subordinate, but carries the authority of God - being given him *by* God as His trusted, loving and *exalted* son.

Answer (score -2):

It is a rhetorical question that contains the answer within itself, and the answer is that "nobody"!

The same Isaiah calls the Son who is to be born as a child - "Mighty God" (Isaiah 9:6). Now, is this "Mighty God" equal to God the Father? Yes, 100%, for He belongs to the very essence of God the Father, so that Father gives Him birth out of His essential necessity. Therefore the Prophet Isaiah does not contradict himself, for how can Holy Spirit, who inspired Isaiah, contradict Himself? Thus in the mentioned rhetorical question is implied the created order of reality, not the Son, who is a co-Creator and co-Mighty God with Him, God the Father, and even co-Father in a certain sense, not hypostatically, but in the sense of being co-Creator of the entirety of the universe, for Isaiah calls the Son also the "Everlasting Father" (Isaiah 9:6).

As to the OP author's question about the Holy Trinity, that it to say, in which sense the Father and the Son and the H. Ghost are one God, which I answered in comments, I think, since it is an important - albeit well-trodden since the Nicaea 325 AD - point, I give my answer with slight modifications also here:

The Trinitarian Persons/Hypostases are one in essence, for when the Father gives birth to the Son eternally and essentially, He gives to the Son in this very birth the entirety of His essence, that is to say, it is not that first Father gives birth to the Son and then gives His essence, but this very natural/necessary and eternal begetting entails the giving of the entirety of His essence; and, likewise, when He emits essentially and necessarily (i.e. not volitionally) the h. Ghost, He gives the entirety of His essence to the H. Ghost. Since this birthgiving/begetting and emission belong to the very Person/Hypostasis of Father *qua* Father so that without it He cannot even be Father, then His eternal and necessary Fatherhood is conditioned by eternal birth of the Son and eternal emission of the h. Ghost, thus all Three having the same and identical worshipable Godhead with respect of Their Essence. It is simply theologically impossible to worship the Father without co-worshipping the Son and the H.Ghost. And such is the depth of soul-destroying error of the Arians and Eunomians, as well as their modern much less sophisticated heirs.